# Gutenberg save data to post meta field when selectControl is changed

Tags: wordpress, react-redux, wordpress-gutenberg

I'm entirely new to React and JSX and have been working on a select menu dropdown field within the WP sidebar.
This select menu shows the currently added post categories, and that part is working perfectly.

Where I come unstuck is how to save this selection and how to update a post meta field with the selected option from the select control area.

I have created a post meta field using register_meta in a functions.php file:

```
<?php
register_meta( 'post', '_myprefix_text_metafield', array(
    'show_in_rest' => true,
    'type' => 'string',
    'single' => true,
    'sanitize_callback' => 'sanitize_text_field',
    'auth_callback' => function ()
    {
        return current_user_can( 'edit_posts' );
    }
) );
```

I then have an index.js file with the following script:

```js
/**
 * https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-plugins/#registerplugin
 * https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/select-control/#usage-2
 */
(function (wp) {
    const { registerPlugin } = wp.plugins;
    const { SelectControl } = wp.components;
    const { PluginDocumentSettingPanel } = wp.editPost;
    const { useSelect } = wp.data;
    const { useState } = wp.element;

    registerPlugin('spectator-primary-category', {
        render: function () {

            const { categories } = useSelect((select) => {
                const { getEntityRecords } = select('core');

                return {
                    categories: getEntityRecords('taxonomy', 'category'),
                }
            })

            let [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState([]);

            let options = [];
            if (categories) {
                options = categories.map(category => ({ label: category.name, value: category.id }));
                options.unshift({ value: 0, label: 'Select a category' });
                console.log(options);
            }

            return (
                <PluginDocumentSettingPanel
                    name="spectator-primary-category-panel"
                    title="Add the primary category"
                    className="spectator-primary-category__panel"
                >
                    <SelectControl
                        value={selectedCategory}
                        options={options}
                        onChange={(tokens) => setSelectedCategory(tokens)}
                    />
                </PluginDocumentSettingPanel>
            )
        },
        icon: 'airplane' // or false if you do not need an icon
    });
})(window.wp);
```

I have spent over 8 hours looking through the internet but haven't been able to achieve what I need. Would any awesome person be able to show me how to save this data, please?

=== Update ===

Thanks to @kofiegan for their help understanding how this works, I was able to update the meta field and display the results. Here is the final code used:

```js
/**
 * https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-plugins/#registerplugin
 * https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/components/select-control/#usage-2
 * https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75816358/gutenberg-save-data-to-post-meta-field-when-selectcontrol-is-changed
 */
(function (wp) {
    const { registerPlugin } = wp.plugins;
    const { SelectControl } = wp.components;
    const { PluginDocumentSettingPanel } = wp.editPost;
    const { useSelect, useDispatch } = wp.data;

    registerPlugin('spectator-primary-category', {
        render: function () {

            const postId = useSelect(
                (select) => select('core/editor').getCurrentPostId(),
                []
            );

            const postType = useSelect(
                (select) => {
                    return select('core/editor').getCurrentPostType();
                }, []
            );

            let editPost = useDispatch('core/editor').editPost;
            let savePost = useDispatch('core/editor').savePost;
            let entityRecordEdits = useSelect(
                (select) => select('core').getEditedEntityRecord('postType', postType, postId),
                []
            );
      
            let getEntityRecord = useSelect(
                (select) => select('core/editor').getEditedPostAttribute('meta')
            );

            // console.log(getEntityRecord);

            function handleChange(tokens) {
                let metaEdits = {
                    meta: {
                        ...entityRecordEdits.meta,
                        _spectator_primary_category_metafield: tokens
                    }
                };

                editPost(metaEdits); // Update the Core Data store (client).
                savePost(metaEdits); // Update the WordPress database (server).
            }
            const { categories } = useSelect((select) => {
                const { getEntityRecords } = select('core');

                return {
                    categories: getEntityRecords('taxonomy', 'category'),
                }
            })

            let options = [];
            if (categories) {
                options = categories.map(category => ({ label: category.name, value: category.id }));
                options.unshift({ value: 0, label: 'Select a category' });
                // console.log(options);
            }

            return (
                <PluginDocumentSettingPanel
                    name="spectator-primary-category-panel"
                    title="Add the primary category"
                    className="spectator-primary-category__panel"
                >
                    <SelectControl
                        value={getEntityRecord._spectator_primary_category_metafield}
                        options={options}
                        onChange={handleChange}
                    />
                </PluginDocumentSettingPanel>
            )
        },
        icon: 'airplane' // or false if you do not need an icon
    });
})(window.wp);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many options for saving meta data. The code snippets below suggest one approach.

## UPDATE

**Answer updated with Aaron's corrections. `getEditedEntityRecord` should be used, not `getEntityRecordEdits`. [getEditedEntityRecord](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-core-data/#geteditedentityrecord) returns the data from the database merged with changes made in the client while [getEntityRecordEdits](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-core-data/#getentityrecordedits) only returns the changes made in the client.**

[getEditedEntityRecord](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-core-data/#geteditedentityrecord) is used to ensure that changes made to post meta fields that were saved to the WordPress *Core Data* data store (data storage in the client) are not lost when updates are made by `handleChange`. [getEntityRecord](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-core-data/#getentityrecord) could have been used instead which would retrieve the latest values stored in the database (data storage on the server), but not the latest changes made in the client.

```
const { useSelect, useDispatch } = wp.data; 

...

const postId = useSelect(
    ( select ) => select( 'core/editor' ).getCurrentPostId(),
    []
);

const postType = useSelect(
    ( select ) => {
        return select( 'core/editor' ).getCurrentPostType();
    }, []
);

let editPost = useDispatch( 'core/editor' ).editPost;
let savePost = useDispatch( 'core/editor' ).savePost;
let entityRecordEdits = useSelect(
    ( select ) => select( 'core' ).getEditedEntityRecord( 'postType', postType, postId ),
    []
);

function handleChange( tokens ) {
    let metaEdits = {
        meta: {
            ...entityRecordEdits.meta,
            META_FIELD_NAME: tokens // Replace META_FIELD_NAME with the name of the desired meta field.
        }
    };

    editPost( metaEdits ); // Update the Core Data store (client).
    savePost( metaEdits ); // Update the WordPress database (server).
    setSelectedCategory(tokens); // Missing from original answer.
}

...

let [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState([]);

...

<SelectControl
    value={selectedCategory}
    options={options}
    onChange={ handleChange }
/>  

...
```

### editPost and savePost

Depending on the desired page behavior, you may not need to call `savePost`.

Calling `editPost` (and not `savePost`) updates the WordPress Core Data store. Color changes in the page's **Update** button give the user feedback that unsaved changes are on the page. You could leave it up to the user to click **Update** to save your *WP sidebar* changes along with any other changes made by the user.

Calling `savePost` immediately saves your *WP sidebar* changes along with any other changes to Post meta made by the user (e.g. from other page form fields that update meta). However, if *WP sidebar* updates to the server **should not** include other changes made to Post meta, then `getEntityRecord` should be used rather than `getEditedEntityRecord`.

Comment: Thank you. I’ll take a look at this tomorrow morning, it looks really promising.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. I still couldn't save the data. EntityRecordEdits was returning undefined. I changed this to getEditedEntityRecord, and bingo, that part started working. Finally, the result in the select field wasn't updating with the selected option, so I updated the value of the select using getEditedPostAttribute. Once these changes were in place, everything worked great! Thank you for being so helpful.

Comment: @Aaron Great. Thanks for posting the updated code. Your changes make sense. I also forgot to add `setSelectedCategory(tokens)` immediately after the call to `savePost`. This would make the call to `getEditedPostAttribute` unnecessary. I've updated my answer to avoid misleading anyone.